# Is there an ES6 method to search an array for elements with elements from another array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays containing some parameter values. All elements in the arrays are strings like the following:

```
x = [ "vorzugsreihe=J", "nennleistung=94,1127", "nenndrehzahl=31,9400"]
y = ["nenndrehzahl=500,3000"]
```

Expected Output would be:

```
x = [ "vorzugsreihe=J", "nennleistung=94,1127", "nenndrehzahl=500,3000"]
```

I have tried using `Array.Filter` but can't seem to be able to filter only partially (like starting with the string instead of the whole string since that won't match as the values are different).

What I'd like is to be able to go through each element from array `Y`, and search if the element(string before "=") exists in array `X` and replace the value(s) of that element in array `X`.

Comment: Please provide the expected output

Comment: Can you please share your `.filter` code?

Comment: @HassanImam I've added the expected output. This is just an example of where the second array has only one element. But it might have more than one

Answer (score 1):

```
for(var i=0;i<x.length;i++){
  var currentStr = x[i];
  var currentInterestedPart = /(.+)=(.+)/.exec(currentStr)[1];
  var replacePart = /(.+)=(.+)/.exec(currentStr)[2];
  for(var j=0;j<y.length;j++){
   if(!y[j].startsWith(currentInterestedPart)) {continue;}
   var innerReplacePart = /(.+)=(.+)/.exec(y[j])[2];
   x[i] = currentStr.replace(replacePart,innerReplacePart);break;
  }
}
```

Try this. This makes use of RegEx and it is less error prone.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Map` and `map`

- First create a Map from array `y`, split each element by `=` use first part as key and second part as value
- Loop over `x` array, split each element by `=` and use first part as key to search in `Map` if it's present use value from `Map` else return without any change

```js
let x = ["vorzugsreihe=J", "nennleistung=94,1127", "nenndrehzahl=31,9400"]
let y = ["nenndrehzahl=500,3000"]

let maper = new Map(y.map(v => {
  let [key, value] = v.split('=', 2)
  return [key, value]
}))

let final = x.map(v => {
  let [key, value] = v.split('=', 2)
  if (maper.has(key)) {
    return key + '=' + maper.get(key)
  }
  return v
})

console.log(final)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
y.forEach(item => {
  const str = item.split("=")[0];
  const index = x.findIndex(el => el.startsWith(str));
  if (index) {
    const split = x[index].split('=');
    x[index] = `${split[0]}=${split[1]}`;
  }
})
```

Comment: This will fail if a value is equal to the key you're looking for, e.g., `vorzugsreihe=nenndrehzahl`

Comment: Now it fails for a case when `y=['abc=2']` and `x=['abcd=3']`

Answer (score 0):

For each value in the `y` array, iterate and check if the word exist in the `x` array. Once you find a match just update the value. (The below solution mutates the original array)

```js
const x = [ "vorzugsreihe=J", "nennleistung=94,1127", "nenndrehzahl=31,9400"],
      y = ["nenndrehzahl=500,3000"],
      result = y.forEach(word => {
        let [str, number] = word.split('=');
        x.forEach((wrd,i) => {
          if(wrd.split('=')[0].includes(str)) {
            x[i] = word;
          }
        });
      });
console.log(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using combination of reduce + find - this would accumulate and give you the results you're expecting.

```js
var x = [ "vorzugsreihe=J", "nennleistung=94,1127", "nenndrehzahl=31,9400"]
var y = ["nenndrehzahl=500,3000"]

var combinedArr = x.reduce((acc, elem, index) => {
  const elemFoundInY = y.find((yElem) => yElem.split("=")[0] === elem.split("=")[0]);
  if (elemFoundInY) {
    acc = [...acc, ...[elemFoundInY]]
  } else {
    acc = [...acc, ...[elem]];
  }
  return acc;
}, [])

console.log(combinedArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.startsWith()` to check if element start with `key=` and then replace its value:

```js
let x = [ "vorzugsreihe=J", "nennleistung=94,1127", "nenndrehzahl=31,9400"];
let y = ["nenndrehzahl=500,3000"];

y.forEach(val => {
  let [key, value] = val.split("=");
  for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if (x[i].startsWith(`${key}=`)) x[i] = `${x[i].split("=")[0]}=${value}`;
  }
})

console.log(x)
```